# Does multiple packages and dependencies effect the size of final build of React-Native android release

Tags: performance, build.gradle, react-native, package.json

I am a month into react-native and going through the learning process. Does adding too many packages somehow affect the size of the final android release. I also want to know if is it good practice to use the same project for multiple apps. Is it safe to use this many dependencies in a single project?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.2.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.220.0",
    "react-native-contacts": "^5.0.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.13"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically Yes

But to see how much each package takes

You should check with this tool
[cost of modules](https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules)

> Cost of modules
>
> Find out which of your dependencies is slowing you down

`npm install -g cost-of-modules`

Run cost-of-modules in the directory you are working in.

`cost-of-modules`

[image]